# URL shows 404 in Inspect's network, URL not indexing. Google says Not Found

Tags: reactjs, indexing, seo, inspect, custom-error-pages

***Network in Inspect after loading the page:***

Request URL: https://www.gativan.in/blog/Request

Method: GET

Status Code: 404

Remote Address: `13.227.254.33:443`

Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin  [image]

[image]

Google says Page not found

Added canonical tags, but didn't work.

Comment: Added this <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.gativan.in/blog" data-react-helmet="true"> , still React Js inspect network shows error

Comment: <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.gativan.in/blog" data-react-helmet="true">

Comment: It is easy to see exactly what Google is seeing.  On the command line: `curl --head https://www.gativan.in/blog/Request/` shows `HTTP/2 404`.

Comment: You need to provide enough information to help you debug the problem. It looks like this is a react project.  How is it deployed?  Have you added the front controller to `.htaccess`?  What is your router code?